# Does this Dice rolling Code have good style

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

Hi guys I just recently started doing my own projects and I'm hoping that as I work through these things that I can make sure to make the code as neat and polished as possible since I am mostly teaching myself.

So I was wondering if this was the best way to do this Dice rolling code:

```
Game = input("Hello there! Would you like to bet your luck on a dice roll?\n")
if Game == "yes"or"Yes":
    print("Well great! Here we go!");
    import random;
    print(random.randint(1, 6));
else:
    print("I guess next time then...");
```

specifically around the "if statement" and trying to account for people using capitalization or non-capitalization. Or just how to create a better way for people to put in a variety of answers.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to compare case-insensitive, you can convert the Strings to lower cases and compare the lower case values such as `string1.lower() == string2.lower():`.

Comment: You should import at the beginning of your source file!

Comment: You may want to read [PEP 8, Style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use tools such as [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) or [pycodestyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle). (Also: no need to use `;` at the end of a line.)

Comment: Also, comparisons don't work like you think they do.

Comment: Did you try running the code? How did it work for you ?

Comment: "Best practices" and "coding style" questions are better asked at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

> So I was wondering if this was the best way to do this Dice rolling
>   code:

To be short: No.

```
Game = input("Hello there! Would you like to bet your luck on a dice roll?\n")
```

This will work, but it you should use lowercase for your 'Game' variable, as this style (called 'CapWords' in PEP 8) are reserved for class names.

```
if Game == "yes"or"Yes":
```

This is basicly executed as:

```
if (Game == "yes") or "Yes":
```

You see what will go wrong here? You probably want something like:

```
if Game == "yes" or Game == "Yes":
```

But even better would be to this:

```
if Game.lower() == "yes":
```

This converts the input to lower case first, so basicly ignoring any capitalization used by the user.

```
    print("Well great! Here we go!");
```

Nothing wrong with this line, except the ';' are not needed in Python.

```
    import random;
```

Imports should be at the top of the file.

```
    print(random.randint(1, 6));
```

Again, the ';' should not be used.

```
else:
    print("I guess next time then...");
```

Again, the ';' should not be used.

If I were to write this program, it would look as follows:

```
import random

answer = input("Hello there! Would you like to bet your luck on a dice roll?\n")

if answer.lower() == "yes":

    print("Well great! Here we go!")

    print(random.randint(1, 6))

else:

    print("I guess next time then...")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips! I'm really excited to work on style and learn more about how to use the most neat and compact code I can.

Answer (score 0):

> Or just how to create a better way for people to put in a variety of answers.

If you were to expand the possible answers, your `if` statement would get pretty long and ugly:

```
if game.lower() == "yes" or game.lower() == "y" or game.lower() == "uh huh" # and so on...
```

So, it would be best to put these in a tuple, and then check if their answer is in the tuple:

```
if game.lower() in ("yes", "y", "uh huh"):
    # the rest of your code here...
```